# Change the frequency of a Pandas datetimeindex from daily to hourly, to select hourly data based on a condition on daily resampled data

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on hourly and sub-hourly time series. However, one of the conditions I need to test is on daily averages. I need to find the days that meet the condition, and then select all hours (or other time steps) from those days to change their values. But right now, the only value that is actually changed is the first hour on the selected day. How can I select and modify every hour?

This is an example of my dataset:

```
In[]:  print(hourly_dataset.head())
Out[]:                      
GHI  DNI  DHI
2016-01-01 00:00:00  0.0  0.0  0.0
2016-01-01 01:00:00  0.0  0.0  0.0
2016-01-01 02:00:00  0.0  0.0  0.0
2016-01-01 03:00:00  0.0  0.0  0.0
2016-01-01 04:00:00  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

And this is the condition I need to check. I saved the indexes that satisfy the condition on the daily standard deviation as `ix`.

```
ix = hourly_dataset['GHI'].resample('D').std()[hourly_dataset['GHI'].resample('D').std() > 300].index

In[]:  print(ix)
Out[]: DatetimeIndex(['2016-05-31', '2016-07-17', '2016-07-18'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

But then I assign a nan value to those days and only the first hour is actually modified to nan.

```
hourly_dataset.loc[ix,'GHI'] = np.nan
In[]:  print(hourly_dataset.loc['2016-05-31','GHI'].head())
Out[]: 
2016-05-31 00:00:00      NaN
2016-05-31 01:00:00      0.0
2016-05-31 02:00:00      0.0
2016-05-31 03:00:00      0.0
2016-05-31 04:00:00      7.4
Freq: H, Name: GHI, dtype: float64
```

I would like all values in that day to be assigned nan.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Possible workaround:**

```
for i in ix:
    hourly_dataset.loc[i.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),'GHI'] = np.nan
```

---

#### Explanation

I had a small look and the issue is when we try to select the index by a `Timestamp`. I was able to reproduce your error.

Consider this example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.date_range(start='2018-01-01', freq='2H', periods=24),
    'GHI': 0
}).set_index('date')


ix = pd.date_range(start='2018-01-01', end='2018-01-02')
df.loc[ix, 'GHI'] = np.nan
print(df.head())
```

Returns:

```
                     GHI
date                    
2018-01-01 00:00:00  NaN
2018-01-01 02:00:00  0.0
2018-01-01 04:00:00  0.0
2018-01-01 06:00:00  0.0
2018-01-01 08:00:00  0.0
```

Maybe not the best, but one work-around would be to loop through the ix and use loc on ix as a datetime string with format YYYY-mm-dd.

```
# df.loc[ix.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), 'GHI'] = np.nan --> does not work
for i in ix:
    df.loc[i.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), 'GHI'] = np.nan
    
print(df.head())

date                    
2018-01-01 00:00:00  NaN
2018-01-01 02:00:00  NaN
2018-01-01 04:00:00  NaN
2018-01-01 06:00:00  NaN
2018-01-01 08:00:00  NaN
```